# Paste column values together in a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to paste together the rowname along with the data in the desired column. I wrote the following code but somehow couldnot find a way to do it correctly.

The desired output will be:  `"a,1,11" "b,2,22"  "c,3,33"`

```
x = data.frame(cbind(f1 = c(1,2,3), f2 = c(5,6,7), f3=c(11,22,33)), row.names= c('a','b','c'))
x
#   f1 f2 f3
# a  1  5 11
# b  2  6 22
# c  3  7 33
do.call("paste", c(rownames(x), x[c('f1','f3')], sep=","))
# [1] "a,b,c,1,11" "a,b,c,2,22" "a,b,c,3,33"
```

Answer (score 5):

Two main points:

1. Use `apply` instead of `do.call(paste, .)`
2. Use `cbind` instead of `c` in this case.

   - If you would rather use `c`, you would need to coerce the row names to a list or column first, eg: `c(list(rownames(x)), x)`

Try the following:

```
 apply(cbind(rownames(x), x[c('f1','f3')]), 1, paste, collapse=",")

       a        b        c 
"a,1,11" "b,2,22" "c,3,33"
```

Comment: I like the idea, except that the `apply` will coerce the data.frame into a matrix.. which you can avoid with `do.call(paste, ...)`..

Comment: @Arun, yes, and then paste coerces to string.  There is no data loss, even with factors

Answer (score 4):

Your `do.call` instructs R to paste the list `c(rownames(x), x[c('f1','f3')])` together. But take a look at your list.

```
> c(rownames(x), x[c('f1','f3')])
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"

[[3]]
[1] "c"

$f1
[1] 1 2 3

$f3
[1] 11 22 33
```

The `c` command takes the elements of each argument and joins them together. This properly deconstructs `x[c('f1','f3')]` but also deconstructs `rownames(x)` in a way you don't want. Obeying the standard [recycling rule](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule), `paste` then takes an item from each list element and patches them together with `sep=","`.

You could fix this by encapsulating `rownames(x)` inside a list structure so that your list of arguments comes out properly:

```
do.call("paste", c(list(rownames(x)), x[c('f1','f3')], sep=","))
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for `do.call` or `apply`:

```
paste(rownames(x),x[[1]],x[[3]] , sep=",")
[1] "a,1,11" "b,2,22" "c,3,33"
```

Comment: if you are passing the column names as a variable, how would you avoid using apply?

Comment: Set `var <- c("f1","f2")` then `x[[ var[1] ]], x[[ var[2] ]]`  or `x[[ "f1" ]], x[[ "f2" ]]`

Comment: really?   And if `var` then becomes `var <- c("f1", "f2", "f3")` then what?

Comment: exactly.. both `do.call` and `apply` come very much in handy.  I think the key issue in the OP is determining which one to use